# Superimposing the text from input form on top of an image

Tags: javascript, html, annotate

I want the text that I write on the input to be shown inside the "engrave-image" div. For some reason, I cannot get it to work. I appreciate your help.

```js
function annotate(obj) {
  var typed = document.getElementById(obj).value;
  document.getElementById("engrave-image").innerHTML = typed;
}
```

```html
<input id="engrave-text" maxlength="15" onkeyup="count_up(this)" onkeyup="annotate(this);">
<div id="engrave-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `obj` directly to reference the input that called then onkeyup event. `obj` passed in is a reference to an element (an input element in this case) and not an `id`, so using `document.getElementById(obj);` doesn't make sense here.

Also you should have quotes around the id attribute in your input.

```js
function annotate(obj) {
  var typed = obj.value;
  document.getElementById("engrave-image").innerHTML = typed;
}
```

```html
<input id="engrave-text" maxlength="15" onkeyup="annotate(this);">
<div id="engrave-image"></div>
```

Comment: The quotes didn't fix problem but it seems like the problem was on the function. I appreciate

Comment: yes you don't use the ID `"engrave-text"` at all that was just a side note